# HTML Selection script between two droplists

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu

I have two droplist in html built using  tag.

```
<select name="List1" id="List1" onclick="GetVal()">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Mercurio</option>
<option value="2">Venus</option>
<option value="3">Tierra</option>
<option value="4">Marte</option>
</select>

<select name="List2" id="List2">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Hg</option>
<option value="2">Ve</option>
<option value="3">Ti</option>
<option value="4">Ma</option>
</select>
```

I have written a script such as the selection of an element from List2 relies on the selection of the corresponding element of List1.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <!CDATA[
function GetVal() {
var LSelect1 = document.getElementById('List1');
var LSelect2 = document.getElementById('List2');
switch (LSelect1.selectedIndex)
{
case 1:
  LSelect2.selectedIndex = 1;
  break;
case 2:
  LSelect2.selectedIndex = 2;
  break;
case 3:
  LSelect2.selectedIndex = 3;
  break;
default:
  LSelect2.selectedIndex = 4;
}
}
// ]]>
</script>
```

However, the function works wrongly for the first element of the List1. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectedIndex` is 0-based.  A simpler way to do things might be like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <!CDATA[
function GetVal() {
    var LSelect1 = document.getElementById('List1');
    var LSelect2 = document.getElementById('List2');

    LSelect2.selectedIndex = LSelect1.selectedIndex;
}
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a newbie with HTML althought I had used the switch-case structure before in Matlab.

Comment: No problem.  As an fyi, if you had used `case 0`, `case 1`, ... things would have probably worked as well. The main thing you were missing was that `selectedIndex` is 0-based. I was just showing a shortcut that worked for this case :)